# Correct way to reset class values in unit testing with setup

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I'm new to Objective-C so please bear with me.

I have a unit test class that looks something like this:

```
static NSString * const kTestingUserID = @"userID";    

@interface UserPreferencesTest

@property(nonatomic) UserPreferences *userPreferences;

@end

@implementation UserPreferencesTest

- (void)setUp {
  [super setUp];
  self.userPreferences = [[UserPreferences alloc] init];
}

- (void)testEmptyDictionary {
  STAssertFalse([self.userPreferences getLockoutStatus:kTestingUserID],
               @"An unset username should always return false");
}

- (void)testBlockManualEntry {
  //lock the username
  [self.userPreferences lockout:kTestingUserID];

  STAssertTrue([self.userPreferences getLockoutStatus:kTestingUserID],
                @"The account has been locked out");
}

@end
```

They call the following methods in the userPreferences Class:

```
- (void)lockout:(NSString *) userID {
  NSMutableDictionary *dictionary =
      [[self.defaults objectForKey:dict] mutableCopy];
  dictionary[userID] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
  [self.defaults setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary]
                    forKey:dict];
  [self synchronize];
}

- (BOOL) getLockoutStatus:(NSString *) userID {
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.defaults objectForKey:dict];
  if ([dictionary objectForKey:userID])
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

If I comment out the testBlockManualEntry the test passes. If I run the two tests together the first one, testEmptyDictionary fails. The issue to my understanding is that the username is set in the 2nd test and then is found in the 1st test.

If I were to write a similar unit test in java I would use @Before in my setup and thus setup would run before each test method is called. That would ensure that the userPreferences is created each time and thus the values in that object are reset.

What am I missing here? My understanding of setup in Objective-C is that it should behave similarly (clearly it's not unless theres another bug that I'm not seeing).

Also please ignore the fact that a set would be better used in this scenario than a dict, I'm just looking (and how to fix the issue) for why the tests fail when run together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest changing over to Xcode's XCT test framework. SN* is an old framework.

Your problem is probably coming from

```
@interface UserPreferencesTest
```

It should be

```
@interface UserPreferencesTest: XCTestCase
```

So that it inherits all the functionality of the test framework. Then it should work.

I also noticed this code:

```
if ([dictionary objectForKey:userID])
    return true;
return false;
```

There is nothing wrong with this code and it will work. But from a style point of view I would change it. Firstly I always recommend ensuring that `if ...` statements always have `{...}` brackets. The reason is that it's easy to miss read a single line `if` and subtle bugs can appears, especially if other developers are updating your code.

The second thing is that whenever I see a `return YES` or `return NO`, I tend to look to see if they are a verbose version of what the code is trying to achieve.
In that light, I would probably code something like this:

```
return [dictionary objectForKey:userID] != nil;
```

Having said that, sometimes code is clearer when you do `return YES` or `return NO`. So it's how you feel about it.

Comment: ah ok, thank you. Appreciate the style comments as well.